# I'm having a frustrating problem with ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, scrollview

I'm working on a UI that has a bunch of images and buttons, but since they're too long to fit on one screen, I decided to put it in a ScrollView. Problem is, once I do that, everything disappears except my first image. Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg" 
    android:baselineAligned="true" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
                android:src="@drawable/header3000" 
                android:layout_gravity="center" 
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"></ImageView>
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/imageView2" 
                android:src="@drawable/websitetuneup" 
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"></ImageView>
            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Read More" android:id="@+id/readmore_w1" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"></Button>
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/imageView3" 
                android:src="@drawable/inboundmarketing" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"></ImageView>
            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Read More" android:id="@+id/readmore_w2" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="right" 
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"></Button>
            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:id="@+id/imageView4" 
                android:src="@drawable/socialmedia" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"></ImageView>
            <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Read More" android:id="@+id/readmore_w3" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"></Button>
            </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's what it looks like

[image]

Notice how the first image appears fine, but all the rest are minimized into a small portion to the right of the image.
How should I fix this? Thanks in advance for your help, and sorry for the long post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orientation of second LinearLayout is not defined. It seems it is takes as horizontal by default. Try the veritical one.